# Is a correlated function in the FROM clause executed for every row?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, optimization, execution-plan

I have a heavy function, let's call it `fcalc(x,y) -> my_z`. I need the result `my_z` to both be a filter (too low and the row is discarded) and in the result set (so my client can see it). I write the query like so:

```
SELECT *, my_z
FROM big_table t, (SELECT * FROM fcalc(t.x, t.y)) as my_z
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND ... AND my_z > $threshold
```

My question is: will all the other conditions apply first which should filter out very large number of rows before it applies `fcalc`? I'm very new to databases.

Comment: Welcome to DBA SE, you might want to include your execution plan as I see you've added it as a tag to your question (as well as overall performance). Also would be beneficial to put the real query here. Because looking at your example, under the assumption that `fcalc` returns a record for each input, then yes, it is executing for each row. But without more context we can't improve or suggest solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO, Postgres typically does not evaluate the function in the `LATERAL` subquery for all rows.**
It will apply simple filters on `big_table` first and execute the function only for rows still in the race.

#### Fix question

Your query is syntactically invalid.
Assuming `fcalc()` returns a single value, this would *work*:

```
SELECT * , my_z
FROM big_table t, LATERAL (SELECT * FROM fcalc(t.x, t.y)) AS f(my_z)
WHERE $condition1 AND $condition2 AND ... AND f.my_z > $threshold
```

And should be untangled to just:

```
SELECT *
FROM   big_table t
JOIN   LATERAL fcalc(t.x, t.y) AS f(my_z) ON f.my_z > $threshold
WHERE  $condition1
AND    $condition2
AND ...
```

Moving the `f.my_z > $threshold` from the `WHERE` clause to the join condition makes the query easier to read and has no effect on the query plan whatsoever (while using `[INNER] JOIN`). This produces the exact same query plan:

```
SELECT *
FROM   big_table t, fcalc(t.x, t.y) f(my_z)
WHERE  $condition1
AND    f.my_z > $threshold
AND    $condition2
AND ...
```

#### Query plan

Either of the fixed queries will first apply predicates filtering rows in `big_table`, **before** executing `fcalc()` and filtering on the result.

You can check with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Say, your `big_table` has 8 rows, 5 of which don't pass your `$conditionN` filters, and 1 of the remaining 3 does not pass `f.my_z > $threshold`. You'll see something like:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1.17 rows=3 width=79) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on big_table t  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=3 width=75) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=3 loops=1)
        Filter: (id > 5)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 5
  ->  Function Scan on fcalc f  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4)
                                (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: (my_z > 9)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.101 ms
Execution Time: 0.043 ms
```

Meaning, `fcalc()` was only executed 3 times in the example. In reality, you should see index scans for the big table, but all the same.

You can further verify this if you set the GUC [**`track_functions`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-FUNCTIONS) to `pl` before executing the query with or without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-FUNCTIONS)

> Enables tracking of function call counts and time used. Specify `pl`
> to track only procedural-language functions, `all` to also track SQL
> and C language functions. The default is `none`, which disables
> function statistics tracking. Only superusers can change this setting.
>
> #### Note
>
> SQL-language functions that are simple enough to be “inlined” into the
> calling query will not be tracked, regardless of this setting.

Then check how often your function has actually been called, before and after executing your query:

```
SELECT calls
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_functions
WHERE  funcid = 'fcalc'::regproc
```

Consult the manual for [details about the cast `'fcalc'::regproc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html#DATATYPE-OID-TABLE).

##### Aside

Postgres will also prioritize filters on the same level by their estimated cost. You can verify with the tools I laid out above. Tinker with the `COST` setting of simple plpgsql functions ...